# Різниця між словами "новації" та "інновації"?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, значення-слів

Яка різниця між словами "новація" та "інновація"? В яких випадках вживаються ці варіанти?

Comment: У чому полягає запитання? Наведені означення є різними, у цьому і є відмінність між значеннями слів, чи не так?

Comment: @bytebuster, такі визначення важко усвідомити, крім того вони не зобов'язані бути повними. Я думаю, варто зробити висновки простими словами + можливо, приклади (<оце> — новація, але не інновація, <оце> — інновація, але не новація, а <оце> — і новація, і інновація).

Comment: @Sasha, саме це я і маю на увазі. Якщо так робити, то ми одразу ж упремося в open-ended list of «оце». Which is off-topic.

Comment: А може, й ні. Можливо, це була спроба не запитати, а надати інформацію… В такому випадку зазначу для автора таке… Stack Exchange не забороняє це, а навіть, навпаки, заохочує. Але: (1) запитання в такому випадку має бути оформлене, як запитання; (2) під час створення запитання треба натиснути на галочку «Answer your own question» і ввести відповідь **в окремому полі**, що з'явиться ничже; (3) відповідь має містити, власне, відповідь (інформацію в тексті), а не бути набором посилань.

Comment: @Sasha, дякую за зауваження.

Comment: @MariiaMatskevych, у даному випадку, якщо чесно, подяки не достатньо. Тут треба: або, якщо це запитання, переформулювати/доповнити його так, щоб було зрозуміло, що саме в наведених Вами ж означеннях Вас не влаштовує (що саме Ви хочете почути у відповідь); або якщо це спроба надати інформацію, то перенести інформативну частину з питання у відповідь.

Comment: @MariiaMatskevych, ну і якщо Ви знаєте відповідь, якщо текст, що Ви прибрали із запитання, Ви вважаєте правильним і прийнятним, то Ви можете самостійно додати його в поле «Post Your Answer». Це не заборонено (відповідати на власні запитання), це навпаки заохочується (відповідати на будь-які запитання, зокрема на власні). (А якщо той фрагмент тексту Ви вважаєте недостатнім для відповіді, з якихось причин він Вас не влаштовує, чогось не вистачає, то треба це явно зазначити, що інші знали, чого Ви чекаєте, а чого ні.)

Answer (score 1):

Згідно до [СУМу](http://sum.in.ua/f/) ці слова можуть мати синонімічне значення: "нововведення". Однак, слово "новація" ще може вживатися в юриспруденції і означає "припинення зобов'язання за згодою сторін через заміну його новим", а "інновація" у може мати також значення: "діяльність спрямована на створення принципово нових, вдосконалених або більш відповідних умовам технологій, виробів тощо"

Answer (score 0):

Вікіпедія дає таке значення даних слів

> **[Новація](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F)** (лат. novatio — зміна, оновлення) у техніці — це
>   результат практичного освоєння нового, ефективність чого оцінюється
>   економічним, соціальним та ін. ефектом. Див. також Винахід.
>
> **Новація** у цивільному праві — угода про заміну одного зобов'язання
>   іншим, яка приводить до припинення існуючого між сторонами
>   зобов'язання й виникнення на його основі нового.
>
> **Новація** — продукт інтелектуальної діяльності людей, оформлений
>   результат фундаментальних, прикладних чи експериментальних досліджень
>   у будь-якій сфері людської діяльності, спрямований на підвищення її
>   ефективності.
>
> **[Іннова́ція](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F)** (англ. innovation — нововведення)— ідея, новітній
>   продукт в галузі техніки, технології, організації праці, управління, а
>   також у інших сферах наукової та соціальної діяльності, засноване на
>   використанні досягнень науки і передового досвіду, є кінцевим
>   результатом інноваційної діяльності.
>
> **Інновація** — це результат системної діяльності, спрямованої на
>   реалізацію досягнень науково-технічного прогресу та їх удосконалень,
>   що сприяє кількісним та якісним змінам у внутрішньому середовищі
>   підприємства та забезпечує підвищення ефективності та отримання
>   конкурентних переваг.
>
> ***Законодавче визначення***
>
> **Інновації** — новостворені (застосовані) і (або) вдосконалені
>   конкурентоздатні технології, продукція або послуги, а також
>   організаційно-технічні рішення виробничого, адміністративного,
>   комерційного або іншого характеру, що істотно поліпшують структуру та
>   якість виробництва і (або) соціальної сфери.
>
> **Інновація** є введенням у споживання якого-небудь нового або значно
>   поліпшеного продукту (товару або послуги) або процесу, нового методу
>   маркетингу, або нового організаційного методу в діловій практиці,
>   організації робочих місць або зовнішніх зв'язків.

СУМ-20

> **[ІННОВАЦІЯ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=176351&page=1232)** ї, ж. Нововведення в галузі техніки, технології, організації праці або управління, засноване на використанні досягнень
>   науки та передового досвіду. *Дослідження, що виконуються приватним
>   сектором економіки, сприяють успішному впровадженню інновацій* (з
>   наук. літ.);

СУМ-11

**[НОВАЦІЯ](http://sum.in.ua/s/novacija)**

> 1. В юриспруденції — припинення зобов'язання за згодою сторін через заміну його новим.
> 2. Нововведення.

**[НОВОВВЕДЕННЯ](http://sum.in.ua/s/novovvedennja)**

> Те нове, яке недавно або тільки що ввели.

Тобто **інновація** це практичне використання чогось нового, а **новація** - це лише ідея, початок використання нового.